# resolv.conf overwritten every time

Tags: debian, openvpn, resolv.conf

I got this

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 root tunnel 100 date and time .
drwxr-xr-x 33 root root 860 date and time …
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root tunnel 0 date and time enable-updates
drwxrwxr-x 2 root tunnel 40 date and time interface
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root tunnel 151 date and time resolv.conf
```

Then I run

```
sudo chown --recursive root:tunnel run/resolvconf
sudo chmod --recursive 775 /run/resolvconf
```

Then I get this

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 root tunnel 100 date and time .
drwxr-xr-x 33 root root 860 date and time …
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root tunnel 0 date and time enable-updates
drwxrwxr-x 2 root tunnel 40 date and time interface
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root tunnel 151 date and time resolv.conf
```

but after few second or reboot all is OVERWRITTEN flags and file resolv.conf
and I get this again

```
ls -al /run/resolvconf
total 4
drwxrwxr-x  3 root tunnel 100 date and time .
drwxr-xr-x 33 root root   860 date and time ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     0 date and time enable-updates
drwxrwxr-x  2 root tunnel  40 date and time interface
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   151 date and time resolv.conf
```

and I cant chattr

```
chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf
```

here is cat for resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND – YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Comment: Someone has already ask this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90059/193164

Answer (score 3):

As it's written the resolv.conf file is overwritten each times you start or restart the network manager demon

If you want to keep a static DNS you've to add this line in you /etc/network/interfaces file :

```
dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

In my example you've to replace `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx` by the IP address of the desired DNS. You could put `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` which is the DNS of Google as example.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/resolv.conf` is just a symbolic link , because you have `resolvconf` package installed on your system the default `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` :

```
/etc/resolv.conf -> /etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf
```

That's why your recive `chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf` error.

Remove the `/etc/resolv.conf` then create it again.

```
rm /etc/resolv.conf # or use unlink command
nano /etc/resolv.conf # etdit your file
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the below command to prevent the `resolv.conf` or any file from being overwritten after reboot:

```bsh
chattr -V +i filename e.g chattr -V +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

To Revert Back the Change Use the below Command:

```bsh
chattr -i filename - to re-enable insert to the file
```

chattr (Change Attribute) is a command line Linux utility that is used to set/unset certain attributes to a file in Linux system to secure accidental deletion or modification of important files and folders, even though you are logged in as a root user.

Comment: If two questions deserve [the same word-for-word answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/546956/116858), the correct thing to do is to flag one question as a duplicate of the other, not to post duplicate answers.

Comment: Also note that the user tried and failed with using `chattr`, and that this is _not_ the correct way to solve this issue.

Comment: Run the  command with sudo permisssion. It will not throw above error  i.e sudo  chattr -V +i filename e.g sudo chattr -V +i /etc/resolv.conf